# Parse Div from url data

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Actually I am new towards web crawling and I am doing it in c# using HtmlAgilityPack. Since I've been stuck on a problem for 2 days which is really being hectic for me. I hope someone could help me out. Here is the attached image of url HTML data. What I want is title name not item.title in output.

[HtmlData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPE4Y.png)

```
    static string url="https://xyzabc.com";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        getJobeeData();
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void getJobeeData()
    {
        HtmlWeb html = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc = html.Load(url);

        var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@ng-href]//p");
        if (title == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
        else if (title != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in title)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Jobee Jobs Data" + item.InnerText + "\n");
            }
        }

    }
```

What i got on output is this :
[OutputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPeCI.png)

Comment: What you are seeing in your output is a template. I'm guessing javascript on the page is loading the data dynamically after the initial get request.
If you look at your network requests (network tab in chrome dev tools) you should see extra calls that get structured data (like json or xml) for that site. Then in your code you can call those endpoints directly and get and parse your data that way.

Comment: Saw the site from your edits and loaded it up and there are separate calls. Looks like you want to use the "jobsbyindustry" and/or the "getsponsoredjobs" endpoints.